# calling a local parse server over the internet

Tags: android, mongodb, heroku, parse-platform, server

Let say that I have a parse server installed locally on my local machine can I use that server outside of the development process and use it while I am not connected to my local WiFi?  Basically is there any way that I can get around having to use a service such as Mongodb or Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can deploy your parse-server on heroku and any server than can run node.js.

[parse-server-example](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-example) is giving the option to install parse server on different platforms including heroku with a 1-click install.